# Use of pronouns ( coppie di pronomi atoni )

Tags: word-meaning, grammar, sentences

> Direte a me la verita.

Are the following successive transformations correct? ->

> Diretemi la verita.

or ->

> Mi direte la verita.

What if we use the "coppie di pronomi atoni"? ->

> Me la direte.

or

> La diretemi.

Comment: kiriloff, please, please stop posting exercises to be corrected. This is not the place to do so. Try reddit or other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pronouns can only be attached to the verb if it's an infinitive, imperative or gerund, e.g.:

- *Ditemi la verità!*
- *Hai giurato di dirmi la verità.*

*Direte* is future, so the sentences with *diretemi* are out of the question. The other two are fine (except for the missing accent in *verità*).

Answer (score 0):

The correct transformations are:

> Mi direte la verità.

> Me la direte.